# Implementing the Algorithm for Erastosthenes Sieve

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm new to programming and python and would like some help with finding the primality of an integer. I've read some approaches to implementing Eratosthene's sieve but most seem a bit too involved (too much code). Here is my approach and the part where I need help is below the #HELP comment:

```
def prime_number(an_integer):
    if (an_integer <= 1):
        return False
    else:
        integer_list = list(range(2, an_integer +1))

        #HELP
        first_element = integer_list[0]
        for each_integer in integer_list:
            if (each_integer % first_element == 0) and (each_integer != first_element):
                integer_list.remove(each_integer)

        second_element = integer_list[1]
        for each_integer in integer_list:
            if (each_integer % second_element == 0) and (each_integer != second_element):
                integer_list.remove(each_integer)

        third_element = integer_list[2]
        for each_integer in integer_list:
            if (each_integer % third_element == 0) and (each_integer != third_element):
                integer_list.remove(each_integer)

        fourth_element = integer_list[0]
        for each_integer in integer_list:
            if (each_integer % fourth_element == 0) and (each_integer != fourth_element):
                integer_list.remove(each_integer)


        print (integer_list)
```

How do I get rid of the repetition?

Comment: A sieve is a good method if you need to generate all primes within a range. If you only want the function to check the primality of `an_integer`, there's no need to use a sieve. All you need is one loop where you check whether `an_integer` is divisible by some other integers. (I'm trying not to give too much away :-) ) You could use something similar to a sieve if you want, but there's no need to store the sieve, because you're only interested in one value in it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question:

```
for element in integer_list:
    for each_integer in integer_list:
        if (each_integer % element == 0) and (each_integer != element):
            integer_list.remove(each_integer)
```

(I'm assuming that you meant for `fourth_element` to be `integer_list[3]`.)

Note, however, that you now have *2* loops over `integer_list`, inside of which you removing elements from that list, which will likely cause you trouble.

Comment: Hello Scott Hunter, apologies for he late reply. I'm grateful for your response and helping to clean out my code. It works fine.